# How to say "to know how to do something"

Tags: translation, word-requests

Is there a generic formula to express "to **know** how to do something"?

I know how to ask a question in the second person "How do you do something?", e.g.

> How do you write "Yasuda" in kanji? 「やすだ」は漢字でどう書きますか。

I also know how to ask

> Can he write "Yasuda" in kanji? 彼は「やすだ」を漢字で書けますか。

but I am struggling to put it in the third person:

> Does he **know** how to write "Yasuda" in kanji?

Comment: `書き方わかりますか？` the focus on "know" as the main verb means you need to use わかる。

Comment: to clarify, "how to do "X" is V<s>ます</s>方（かた）。Full sentence: `漢字で「やすだ」の書き方はわかる？`

Comment: @frei it should be 漢字での「やすだ」の書き方. 方 is a noun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's あの人は「やすだ」は漢字でどうやって書くか知っていますか？, generally, to know how to do something is どう（やって）…するか（を）知っている.